# c++ template subclass calling wrong parent constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm using the wrapper template class of Stroustrup:

```
template<class T, class Pref, class Suf>
class Wrap {
protected: 
    T* p;
    int* owned;
    void incr_owned() { if (owned) ++*owned; }
    void decr_owned() { if (owned && --*owned == 0) { delete p; delete owned; } }

    Pref prefix;
    Suf suffix;
public:
    Wrap(T& x, Pref pr, Suf su)
        :p(&x), owned(0), prefix(pr), suffix(su) { } 

    Wrap(T* pp, Pref pr, Suf su)
        :p(pp), owned(new int(1)), prefix(pr), suffix(su) { } 

    Wrap(const Wrap& a)
        :p(a.p), owned(a.owned), prefix(a.prefix), suffix(a.suffix)
        { incr_owned(); }
```

I'm subclassing it to create a threadsafe object:

```
template<class DSP> class DspWrap : public Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()> {
protected:
    CriticalSection* criticalSection;

public:
    DspWrap(DSP& x) : Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()>(x, &DspWrap::prefix, &DspWrap::suffix) { 
    }

    DspWrap(DSP* pp) : Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()>(pp, &DspWrap::prefix, &DspWrap::suffix) { //compiler error here
    }
```

But when in the line creating the object `DspWrap<PpmDsp> wrap = DspWrap<PpmDsp>(new PpmDsp());` I get the following error `error C2664: 'Wrap<T,Pref,Suf>::Wrap(T &,Pref,Suf)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PpmDsp *' to 'PpmDsp &'`

But why is it calling the wrong constructor? There actually IS a constructor for `PpmDsp*`, so why does it try to call `PpmDsp&`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use tags to format your code.  Just indent it by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button.  For snippets inline with text, surround the code with backticks.

Comment: Did you intend to initialize `Wrap::prefix` and `Wrap::suffix` to *themselves* ? Likewise with `criticalSection`, but by assignment rather than initializer.

Comment: You do not show proper code on how you create DspWrap instance (it is a template but you create it like it is simple type). Are we missing something?

Comment: Sorry WhozCraig, the `criticalSection` part was wrong, but `prefix` and `suffix` are methods of `DspWrap`. I just cutted them out.
Slava, I don't get your question, sorry.

Comment: Not according to *posted* code (one of the many reasons posting real, *complete* code is so important), and what appears to be happening is you're sending the address of the *`Wrap::` members `prefix` and `suffix` to the base class constructor, of which there is no matching constructor. Posting a sample that works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *what* you're trying to do with regards to initializing members to themselves, but you need proper construction parameters for the base class, and the base class *members* *themselves* aren't the way to do that.

Once i declared two *real* functions for `prefix` and `suffix` the rest works and the base constructor initializes correctly. Since I don't have your definitions of `CriticalSection` or `DSP` I somewhat have to fake this sample, but....

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int CriticalSection;

template<class T, class Pref, class Suf>
class Wrap {
protected:
    T* p;
    int* owned;
    void incr_owned() { if (owned) ++*owned; }
    void decr_owned() { if (owned && --*owned == 0) { delete p; delete owned; } }

    Pref prefix;
    Suf suffix;
public:
    Wrap(T& x, Pref pr, Suf su)
        :p(&x), owned(0), prefix(pr), suffix(su) { }

    Wrap(T* pp, Pref pr, Suf su)
        :p(pp), owned(new int(1)), prefix(pr), suffix(su) { }
};

template<class DSP> class DspWrap : public Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()> {
protected:
    CriticalSection* criticalSection;

    // implemenations of these
    static void prefix_fn() {};
    static void suffix_fn() {};

public:
    DspWrap(DSP& x)
        : Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()>(x, &prefix_fn, &suffix_fn)
        , criticalSection(new CriticalSection)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    DspWrap(DSP* pp)
        : Wrap<DSP, void(*)(), void(*)()>(pp, &prefix_fn, &suffix_fn)
        , criticalSection(new CriticalSection)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct MyDSP { };

int main()
{
    MyDSP dsp;
    DspWrap<MyDSP> wrap1(dsp);

    MyDSP *dsp2 = new MyDSP;
    DspWrap<MyDSP> wrap2(dsp2);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
DspWrap<MyDSP>::DspWrap(DSP &) [DSP = MyDSP]
DspWrap<MyDSP>::DspWrap(DSP *) [DSP = MyDSP]
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right, the function pointers have been wrong. Once I changed them to your example it compiled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`&DspWrap::prefix` is of type `Pref*`. You pass it to the constuctor of `Wrap`, which expects an object of type `Pref`. Passing `DspWrap::prefix` instead would be syntactically correct.

However, `DspWrap::prefix` is not yet initialized when it is passed to the constructor of `Wrap`, so actually calling `Wrap::prefix` afterwards has undefined behaviour.

Comment: I agree on the syntax. The actual symbol, according to the *posted* code from the OP, is the base-member, and I concur that initializing it to its uninitialized "self" is probably not what is intended at all.